# Как сделать так, чтобы при адаптиве блок вытеснялся?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, img

Подскажите, как можно реализовать эти два блока так, чтобы при уменьшении размера экрана картинка слева уезжала за края, а не теснила блок c текстом. 1 пример - макет.

[image: макет]

[image: сверстанный мною пример]

[image: пример при адаптиве]

```
    <div class="content-middle__block">
        <div class="content-middle__block-image">
            <img class="content-middle__block-image-content" src="img/content-middle/iPhone%206.jpg" alt="">
         </div>

        <div class="content-middle__block-text">
            <h2 class="content-middle__block-title">Your day is protected</h2>

            <p class="content-middle__block-p block-p1">There have not been any since we have lived here, said my mother. </p>
            <p class="content-middle__block-p block-p2">We thought - Mr. Copperfield thought - it was quite a large rookery; but the nests were very old ones, and the birds have deserted them a long while.</p>

       <div class="content-middle__block-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="content-middle__block-buttons-item button-item1">
               Try to hack us
                <img src="img/content-middle/icon/Arrow%20Icon.svg" alt="" class="button-icon-content">
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="content-middle__block-buttons-item button-item2">Learn more
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>


    </div>
```

```
.content-middle__block-image {
    transform: translateX(-100px);


}



.content-middle__block-image-content {

}

.content-middle {
    overflow: hidden;
}


.content-middle__block {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;


    padding-top: 108px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
}

.content-middle__block-title {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;

    line-height: 52px;

    max-width: 223px;

    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.content-middle__block-text {

    margin-right: 30px;
    max-width: 469px;
}

.content-middle__block-p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;

    color: #8C8F94;

    line-height: 28px;
}

.block-p1 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.block-p2 {
    margin-bottom: 85px;
}




.content-middle__block-buttons-item {
    position: relative;

    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;

    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;

    padding: 10px 31px 13px 31px;

    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-middle__block-buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.button-item1 {
    width: 162px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.button-icon-content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 47px;

    right: 22px;
    bottom: 16px;
}

.button-item1:hover {
    width: 205px;

    color: white;

    background-color: #267DF4;
    border: 1px solid #267DF4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .content-middle__block-image {

        width: calc(100vw - 500px);

    }

    .content-middle__block-image img {
       width: calc(100vw - 500px);
       height: 100vh;
       display: block;
       background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518117946207-d26b51185902?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position-x: 100%;
    }



    .content-middle__block-image-content {

    }

    .content-middle {
        overflow: hidden;
    }


    .content-middle__block {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;


        padding-top: 108px;
        padding-bottom: 42px;
    }

    .content-middle__block-title {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;

        line-height: 52px;

        max-width: 223px;

        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .content-middle__block-text {

        margin: 30px;
        width: 460px;
    }

    .content-middle__block-p {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;

        color: #8C8F94;

        line-height: 28px;
    }

    .block-p1 {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .block-p2 {
        margin-bottom: 85px;
    }




    .content-middle__block-buttons-item {
        position: relative;

        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;

        display: inline-block;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;

        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 50px;

        padding: 10px 31px 13px 31px;

        transition: all 0.3s ease;

        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content-middle__block-buttons {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .button-item1 {
        width: 162px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .button-icon-content {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 47px;

        right: 22px;
        bottom: 16px;
    }

    .button-item1:hover {
        width: 205px;

        color: white;

        background-color: #267DF4;
        border: 1px solid #267DF4;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="content-middle__block">
        <div class="content-middle__block-image">
            <img class="content-middle__block-image-content" src=" data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw== " alt="">
         </div>

        <div class="content-middle__block-text">
            <h2 class="content-middle__block-title">Your day is protected</h2>

            <p class="content-middle__block-p block-p1">There have not been any since we have lived here, said my mother. </p>
            <p class="content-middle__block-p block-p2">We thought - Mr. Copperfield thought - it was quite a large rookery; but the nests were very old ones, and the birds have deserted them a long while.</p>

       <div class="content-middle__block-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="content-middle__block-buttons-item button-item1">
               Try to hack us
                <img src="img/content-middle/icon/Arrow%20Icon.svg" alt="" class="button-icon-content">
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="content-middle__block-buttons-item button-item2">Learn more
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>


    </div>
```

[image: широкий формат]

[image: узкий формат]

Comment: Можете обьяснить, пожалуйста ?